# Combo Box Binding Phone 8.1 UAP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How do i bind properly to a combox on windows phone 8.1 I tried what i would normally do in winforms but it didnt work. Also this is for a settings page is their any standard practise yet for a 8.1 Phone Store app to create a settings page same way silverlight did.

And before you ask yes the data is their fine have dubged that.

```
public class City
{
  public string id { get; set; }
  public string timing_title { get; set; }
}
public class CitysList
{
  public List<City> cityList { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that DisplayMmember path would work when its set from item source

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCitys" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding timing_title}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" Height="51">

</ComboBox>
```

How i Fetech the data

```
popcornpk_Dal _dal = new popcornpk_Dal();

CitysList _mycities = await _dal.GetCityListAsync();
cboCitys.ItemsSource = _mycities.cityList;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DisplayMemberPath` is used to specify the path to the displayed property, you don't need to bind it

```
DisplayMemberPath="timing_title"
```

beside that it would be much more elegant if you bind your `combobox`'s `itemSource` to a Collection property, and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `CitysList` class, like so :

```
public class CitysList:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ObservableCollection<City> _citylist  ;
        public ObservableCollection<City> CityList
        {
            get
            {
                return _citylist;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_citylist == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _citylist = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }            
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;            
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Xaml

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CitysList}" DisplayMemberPath="timing_title" />
```

and don't forget to set the `DataContext` to an instance of the class that hold the collection, and to update the List just reinstantiate it

```
CityList = new ObservableCollection<City>(await _dal.GetCityListAsync());
```

**Update**

To set the `dataContext`,

**First** Create a `CityList` property in the codebehind,

```
 private CitysList _cityList ;
    public CitysList CityList
    {
        get
        {
            return _cityList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_cityList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _cityList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Second**, set the page `DataContext` to the codebehind using

```
this.DataContext=this; //in the main constructor
```

or from Xaml using

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

the `Combobox` will automatically inherit the page `DataContext`

**Third** Bind to your collection

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCitys" ItemsSource="{Binding CityList.CityList}" DisplayMemberPath="timing_title"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="343" Height="51">
```

PS: you may as well consider adding the `CityList` collection directly in your codebehind there are no need to add a class just to hold that collection !

Comment: I jsut have always used item source can you show me how to set the data context for it thanks and ill mark as answer?

Comment: I am getting this error on CityList = what is wrong here can you give example how i set the data up to comoboxo plz

Comment: check the update, let me now if you need something else

Comment: i getter error still here are u missing something the name of attrirbute? CityList = new ObservableCollection<City>(await _dal.GetCityListAsync());

Comment: there a CityList Collection inside a CityList Object, where are you instantiating the Collection  using the asynchronous code ?

Comment: CityList = new ObservableCollection<City>(await _dal.GetCityListAsync()); but u obv need ot give this a name i was just wanting a simple example on how to bind to combobox this has not helped